# Mutliple inputs with line breaking

Tags: line-breaking, indentation, algorithm2e

I am trying to write an algorithm with multiple inputs in `algorithm2e`.

The result I would like to have is something like

```
Algorithm
-------------------
Input: Input number 1
       Input number 2
       Input number 3

[Some clever algorithm]
```

The best I could do yet was one of those two solutions

```
\begin{algorithm}
\KwIn{Input number 1}
\KwIn{Input number 2\\ Input number 3
\end{algorithm}
```

which archives

```
Algorithm
-------------------
Input: Input number 1
Input: Input number 2
Input number 3
```

Any idea how to get the desired result?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can define a new command to give you the desired indentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\newlength\mylen
\newcommand\myinput[1]{%
  \settowidth\mylen{\KwIn{}}%
  \setlength\hangindent{\mylen}%
  \hspace*{\mylen}#1\\}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\KwIn{Input number 1}
\myinput{Input number 2}
\myinput{Input number 3 spanning more than one line just as an illustration for the example}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using \usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}, the additional input lines receive a linenumber. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 10):

```
\SetKwInOut{Input}{input}  
\Input{a\\
b\\
c  
}
```

works fine

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This is a good to suggestion.  To help future visitors please make this in to a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), cf. Gonzalo Medina's answer.

Answer (score 7):

I solved the problem by using `\newline` instead of `\\`. Here it is a working example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,dotocloa]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[!h]
    \SetAlgoLined
    \small
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \LinesNumbered

    \KwIn{Input 1\newline
            Input 2\newline
            Input 3}

    Some smart pseudocode line 1 \;
    Some smart pseudocode line 2 \;
    Some smart pseudocode line 3 \;

    \KwOut{ Output 1\newline
            Output 2}
    \caption{My Fabulous Algorithm}

\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This seems to be also a good solution, but it will be even more helpful if you edit it to become a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), which should begin with ``\documentclass{...}`` and end with ``\end{document}``.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the defined command `\Indp` in the package

```
    \KwIn{\\
            \Indp \Indp
            Input 1 \\ 
            Input 2 \\
            Input 3
    }
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
    abc
    \begin{algorithm}
        \KwIn{\\
            \Indp \Indp
            Input 1 \\ 
            Input 2 \\
            Input 3
        }
        \Begin{
            Instruction \;
            Instruction \;
            Instruction \;
            Instruction \;
        }
    \end{algorithm}
    abc
\end{document}
```

[image]